# Error Matlab: 'xnodes and ynodes must be monotone increasing'

Tags: matlab, contour

I have this problem that seems easy to fix, but I can't get it yet. I have a function Z defined over X & Y 2d coordinates on a map. I need to interpolate it using another coordinates xnodes, ynodes. When I pass in the info into:

```
Zi = gridfit(X,Y,Z,xnodes,ynodes)
```

or other code:

```
Zi = RegularizeData3D(X,Y,Z,xnodes,ynodes)
```

I get the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> gridfit at 404
xnodes and ynodes must be monotone increasing
```

I've tried:

```
[yi idyi] = sort(ynodes,'ascend');
xi = xnodes(idyi);
Zi = gridfit(X,Y,Z,xi,yi)
```

and get the same error message. Any ideas how to solve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your X and Y vectors must be increasing, i.e. evenly spaced. If they aren't then you could use the scatteredinterpolant class.

Comment: you mean the xnodes, y nodes?

Comment: They are the search coordinates so they can be anywhere, it's the points over which the interpolant is defined that must be regular.